# How to mount a cryptsetup container just with `mount`?

Tags: mount, luks, dm-crypt, cryptsetup

I created an encrypted container via

```
#!/bin/bash
dd if=/dev/zero of=$1 bs=1 count=0 seek=$2
MAPPER=$(mktemp -up /dev/mapper)
LOOPDEV=$(losetup --find --show $1)
cryptsetup luksFormat $LOOPDEV
cryptsetup luksOpen $LOOPDEV $(basename $MAPPER)
mkfs.ext3 $MAPPER
cryptsetup luksClose $MAPPER
losetup -d $LOOPDEV
```

i.e. a file e.g. `container` specified to this script will contain a ext3 filesystem encrypted via `cryptsetup luksFormat`.

To mount it, I currently use another script, say `dm.mount container /mnt/decrypted`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
MAPPER=$(mktemp -up /dev/mapper)
LOOPDEV=$(losetup --find --show $1)
cryptsetup luksOpen $LOOPDEV $(basename $MAPPER) || losetup -d $LOOPDEV
mount $MAPPER $2 || (
  cryptsetup luksClose $MAPPER
  losetup -d $LOOPDEV
)
```

and to unmount it `dm.umount /mnt/decrypted`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
MAPPER=$(basename $(mount | grep $1 | gawk ' { print $1 } '))
LOOPDEV=$(cryptsetup status $MAPPER | grep device | gawk ' { print $2 } ')
umount $1
cryptsetup luksClose $MAPPER
losetup -d $LOOPDEV
```

There's a lot of redundancy and manually grabbing a loop device and mapper both of which could remain anonymous. Is there a way to simply do something like `mount -o luks ~/container /mnt/decrypted` (prompting for the passphrase) and `umount /mnt/decrypted` the easy way instead?

---

**edit** Basically I am happy with my scripts above (although the error checking could be improved...), so

> How can a mount option `-o luks=~/container` be implemented similar to `-o loop ~/loopfile` using the scripts I wrote?

Can this be achieved without rewriting `mount`? Or alternatively, could `-t luks -o loop ~/container` be implemented?

Comment: Have you tried [cryptmount](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptmount)?

Comment: @jw013 I haven't and it might have simplified things a bit, but it also doesn't natively support directly using `mount`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, modifying `mount` is possible, as I learned from the existence of `mount.ntfs-3g`. I'm doing only guesswork, but I suspect `mount -t sometype` results in a call to `mount.sometype $DEV $MOUNTPOINT $OPTIONS`, feel free to correct me here or quote some actual documentation. Especially the option `-o loop` is already treated so there's no need for `lopsetup` anymore...

Symlink/create the mount script as `/sbin/mount.crypto_LUKS`. Remove the loopdevice part and instead just use the `-o loop` switch. Here's my `/sbin/mount.crypto_LUKS`:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
if [[ $(mount | grep ${2%%/} | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; then
  echo "Path $2 is already mounted!" >&2
  exit 9
else
  MAPPER=$(mktemp -up /dev/mapper)
  cryptsetup luksOpen $1 $(basename $MAPPER)
  shift
  mount $MAPPER $* || cryptsetup luksClose $(basename $MAPPER)
fi
```

Now I just have to run `mount -o loop ~/container /mnt/decrypted`, and `mount` will prompt me for the password and then mount the container, automatically releasing the loopdevice once the container is closed. If the decrypted filesystem fails to mount, the container will be closed again, but you can modify that of course. Or implement some option parsing instead of passing everything on to `mount`.

I was hoping the same could be achieved via `/sbin/umount.luks`, but `umount /mnt/decrypted` (even with `-t crypto_LUKS`) still only does the usual unmount, leaving the container open. If you find a way to have `umount` call my `dm.umount` script instead, please let me know... At the moment, directly calling `umount` is discouraged since you will have to figure out the `/dev/mapper` name to manually `cryptsetup luksClose $MAPPER`. At least the loop device will be release automatically if `mount -o loop` was used before...

Comment: Concerning the `umount`, I guess I'll have to [modify the `/etc/mtab` entry of my `mount.luks`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12952686/321973) such that the filesystem type is e.g. `luks.ext3` instead of `ext3`.

Answer (score 3):

pam_mount, [available from sourceforge](http://pam-mount.sourceforge.net/), ships with a helpful mount.crypto_LUKS and umount.crypto_LUKS which overcome some of the shortcomings of the script provided by the other poster.